# graylog mongdb configuration with user password on docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, graylog

I'a trying to set a mongodb user password whend makeing a docker-compose file for graylog.

But i can't set up the user and the password correctly.

here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2'
services:
  # MongoDB: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.2
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
    environment: 
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=graylog
    ports:
      # mongodb
      - 27017:27017
  # Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/docker.html
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2
    volumes:
      - es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=localhost
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1g
  # Graylog: https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog/graylog/
  graylog:
    image: graylog/graylog:4.1
    volumes:
      - graylog_data:/usr/share/graylog/data
    environment:
      # CHANGE ME (must be at least 16 characters)!
      - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper
      # Password: admin
      - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://127.0.0.1:9000/
      - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/graylog
      - GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/graylog
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - GRAYLOG_MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
      - GRAYLOG_MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    entrypoint: /usr/bin/tini -- wait-for-it elasticsearch:9200 --  /docker-entrypoint.sh
    links:
      - mongodb:mongo
      - elasticsearch
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      # Graylog web interface and REST API
      - 9000:9000
      # Syslog TCP
      - 1514:1514
      # Syslog UDP
      - 1514:1514/udp
      # GELF TCP
      - 12201:12201
      # GELF UDP
      - 12201:12201/udp
# Volumes for persisting data, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/
volumes:
  mongo_data:
    driver: local
  es_data:
    driver: local
  graylog_data:
    driver: local
```

but i still have a :

> graylog_1        | 2021-06-30 07:00:32,022 INFO :
> org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster description not yet available.
> Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out graylog_1        | 2021-06-30
> 07:00:32,022 INFO : org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor
> thread while connecting to server localhost:27017 graylog_1        |
> com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
> graylog_1        |    at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
> ~[graylog.jar:?] graylog_1        |   at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128)
> ~[graylog.jar:?] graylog_1        |   at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
> [graylog.jar:?] graylog_1        |    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292] graylog_1        |
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
> refused)

So any idea how to specify the user / password in the docker compose file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that the connection is refused (=the port is closed). This is because you have used `localhost` as the database address here:

```yaml
- GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/graylog
```

Change `localhost` for `mongodb`:

```yaml
- GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://user:password@mongodb:27017/graylog
```

Under normal circumstances `localhost` inside a container refers to the container itself. Since `graylog` container does not have a `mongodb` instance inside it, it tells you that there is nothing listening on `localhost:27017` in `graylog` container.

After this change `graylog` may tell you that it cannot connect due to bad credentials. This is because user created by `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` is added to the `admin` database (not 'graylog'). I guess you need to create a user manually if you haven't already.

Also, these:

```yaml
- MONGODB_URI=mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/graylog
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
- GRAYLOG_MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
- GRAYLOG_MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

have no effect on `graylog`.